# Accessing a scene property from geometry node

Tags: timeline

I am wondering if one can retrieve a certain value from a scene in order to use it further in a geometry node. More specifically I use the Sun position built-in add-on, thus I can see the current time in the following python object

`bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sun_pos_properties.time`

I would like to plug this value as an input for a text object in my scene so I could display the current time across an animation (I keyframed the sun course). Basically the node would look like this, replacing "seconds" output of "Scene Time" by the actual time:

[image]

Hope I'm clear enough, let me know if you have any suggestion.

Thanks !

Vincent.

Comment: Why don’t you use the input node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me this python script works:

```
import bpy


bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = str(bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_current)

print(str(bpy.data.scenes[0].frame_current))

bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"].show_viewport = True
```

i needed this "show_viewport" line that GN will be updated. There might be a more elegant solution.
If you put this in a frame-update handler, you should get what you need. Of course, you should replace the frame with your time value from your add-on which i couldn't test because i don't have this add-on. I just showed you here the principle how it can work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris for this solution, I'll try it.

Comment: You are welcome